# Method not recognizing boolean value

Tags: ruby

I have a method which take two arguments. A value (fixnum) and a boolean.

However, line 4 isn't returning "C" and is returning "D". It isn't recognizing the boolean value and I am unsure why?

```
def grade(num_books, reads_books)
  if num_books < 10 
    return "D"
  elsif num_books < 10 && reads_books == true
    return "C"
  elsif num_books.between?(10, 20)
    return "C"
  elsif num_books.between?(10,20) && reads_books == true
    return "B"
  elsif num_books > 20
    return "B"
  else
    return "A"
  end
end

grade(9, true)
```

Comment: What are the rules for calculating the grade? In particular, the "A" grade cannot be reached, because `num_books` is either below 10, or between 10 and 20, or above 20. There isn't another "else" that could be met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of clauses matters. The first one condition met wins. You might reorder clauses to make it robust enough:

```
def grade(num_books, reads_books)
  if num_books < 10 && reads_books == true
    return "C"
  elsif num_books.between?(10,20) && reads_books == true
    return "B"
  elsif num_books < 10 
    return "D"
  elsif num_books.between?(10, 20)
    return "C"
  elsif num_books > 20
    return "B"
  else
    return "A"
  end
end

grade(9, true)
```

or, a bit more rubyish:

```
def grade(num_books, reads_books)
  if reads_books
    case num_books
    when 0...10 then "C"
    when 10..20 then "B"
    else "A"
    end
  else
    case num_books
    when 0...10 then "D"
    when 10..20 then "C"
    else "B"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think `elsif num_books < 10` should go as a second condition clause. UPD: now I doubt it matters. UPD2: I again think it should go above the `elsif num_books.between?(10,20) && reads_books == true` as it looks more logical to me :D

Comment: The correct answer to your doubts is: `elsif` should be avoided in ruby :)

Comment: Yes, in general of course it should be avoided :) Which for sure makes my above reflections pointless.

Comment: The methods are not equivalent. The first one always returns `"B"` if `num_books` is above 20, whereas the second one returns `"B"` or `"A"` depending on `reads_books` in that case.

Comment: In fact, the original method's `else` cannot be reached – `"A"` is never returned. So this is most likely another bug you have fixed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is returning `"D"` because it passes the condition `if num_books < 10`.